# Doubt about a conterexample about the Lebesgue Dominated Convergence Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

just a quick question to check if this is right. So i have been trying to find a counterexample when we cant swap the limit with the integral when the fuction isnt dominated and i was wondering if this works.

$f_n(x) = \chi_{[n,\infty]}$

$f(x) = \lim_{n \to \infty} f_n(x)$

$\int f_n(x) = \infty$

$\int f(x) =0$

Is this correct? Thanks

Comment: This has the defect that the $f_n$ are not $L^1$ functions. Can you adapt this to make the $f_n$ have finite integrals with $\int f_n\to\infty$, but all the other statements remain true?

Answer (score 1):

As you have been told in the comments, no $f_n$ is integrable. You can take $f_n=n\chi_{\left[0,\frac1n\right]}$ instead.